# Write an Observable Collection to Csv file

Tags: c#, mvvm

I have a datagridview that is bound to an observable collection in a mvvm fashion.
I'm trying to figure out how to write the collection to a csv file.

I can format the headers and get that put in, but not sure how one would iterate over a collection pulling out the values and putting them to a file with comma delimiting.

Here is my class

```
public class ResultsModel
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public int Phone { get; set; }
        public string Username { get; set; }
        public bool Sucess { get; set; }
        public string MessageType { get; set; }
        public string SenderMessageSent { get; set; }
        public string SenderMessageReceived { get; set; }
    }
```

which gets loaded into an observable collection

Comment: Are you asking how to write a loop?

Comment: @EdPlunkett yeah i think OP wants to write a loop.

Comment: @AVKNaidu Well, I'm sure somebody around here has stumbled upon the secret.

Comment: I can loop through it using a foreach no problem, just not sure how to get the values of the properties to a a string builder with a comma delimited format

Comment: @Tbooty What did you try? When you declared a `StringBuilder`, did Intellisense show any methods or properties on it?

Comment: Did you try something to combine the strings as comma separated? What did you attempt so far? Can we see where you have the issue?

Comment: When I foreach through my collection it gives me a list of objects back which are in that collection, I can't to string that object, I need to be able to foreach through the properties at that point to grab the values.

Or am I over thinking this?

Comment: Well I figured it out, but there's got to be an easier way.

the current solution I have is to override the to string method and literally just do property + "," + property

Comment: See. Few mins and you figured it out. And I would recommend you to do the same.

Comment: `string.Join(",", [place values here, calling ToString() as needed])` for all your delimited needs.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a generic helper method which utilizes reflection to get values of all properties in the collection of objects and serializes to comma separated values string. (1 line = 1 object from collection)

```
public static IEnumerable<string> ToCsv<T>(IEnumerable<T> list)
        {
            var fields = typeof(T).GetFields();
            var properties = typeof(T).GetProperties();

            foreach (var @object in list)
            {
                yield return string.Join(",",
                                         fields.Select(x => (x.GetValue(@object) ?? string.Empty).ToString())
                                               .Concat(properties.Select(p => (p.GetValue(@object, null) ?? string.Empty).ToString()))
                                               .ToArray());
            }
        }
```

And the examplary usage:

```
var oemResultsModels = new List<OemResultsModel>
                                   {
                                       new OemResultsModel
                                       {
                                           FirstName = "Fname1",
                                           LastName = "LName1",
                                           MessageType = "Type1",
                                           Phone = 1234567,
                                           SenderMessageReceived = "something1",
                                           SenderMessageSent = "somethingelse1",
                                           Sucess = true,
                                           Username = "username1"
                                       },
                                       new OemResultsModel
                                       {
                                           FirstName = "Fname2",
                                           LastName = "LName2",
                                           MessageType = "Type2",
                                           Phone = 123456789,
                                           SenderMessageReceived = "something2",
                                           SenderMessageSent = "somethingelse2",
                                           Sucess = false,
                                           Username = "username2"
                                       }
                                   };

            using (var textWriter = File.CreateText(@"C:\destinationfile.csv"))
            {
                foreach (var line in ToCsv(oemResultsModels))
                {
                    textWriter.WriteLine(line);
                }
            }
```